# TaskDialog window height is incorrect when an icon is specified

Tags: c#, windows-api-code-pack, taskdialog

**EDIT :**

I have fixed the sources of the Code Pack and uploaded an updated NuGet package :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/

Thanks to **dmex** for the bug fix :
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=108

As you can see, problem is fixed and no need to use the cumbersome syntax of `Opened` event:

[image]

---

When specifying an icon, the dialog height is incorrect; last command link isn't entirely visible :

[image]

Do you have an idea on how to fix this issue ?

Code used for showing this dialog :

```
var dialog = new TaskDialog
{
    Caption = Title,
    InstructionText = "Some files added are already in the collection.",
    Text = "They have been skipped."
};
dialog.Opened += (s1, e1) => { dialog.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Warning; };

var linkContinue = new TaskDialogCommandLink("Continue", "Continue", string.Empty);
linkContinue.Click += (s2, e2) =>
{
    var s = (TaskDialogCommandLink)s2;
    var taskDialog = (TaskDialog)(s.HostingDialog);
    taskDialog.Close();
};
dialog.Controls.Add(linkContinue);

var linkView = new TaskDialogCommandLink("View", "View these files", string.Empty);
linkView.Click += (s3, e3) =>
{
    var s = (TaskDialogCommandLink)s3;
    var taskDialog = (TaskDialog)(s.HostingDialog);
    taskDialog.Close();
    var window1 = new Window1 { Text = files, Title = Title };
    window1.ShowDialog();
};
dialog.Controls.Add(linkView);

dialog.Show();
```

Comment: @Aybe...Any idea why the GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.Photo.DateTaken) in the API doesnt return a string or a DateTime? and whatever it is returning, which I cant seem to figure out, is NOT convertible to a DateTime

Comment: and what library is the Window1  object coming from, I cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try assigning "InstructionText" in .Opend even once again (seems to fix the problem in 1.1.0.0 as well).

```
        var dialog = new TaskDialog
        {
            Caption = Title,
            InstructionText = "Some files added are already in the collection.",
            Text = "They have been skipped."
        };

        dialog.Opened += (s1, e1) =>
        {
            dialog.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Warning;
            dialog.InstructionText = dialog.InstructionText; // < seems to work
        };
```

Comment: Actually there's a bug in the library preventing such syntax : icon won't be shown so that's why it's done in Opened.

Comment: Where did you get your API code pack ? Mine is from Nuget (version 1.1.0.0).

Comment: Nuget, VS2012 (NET 4.5), the "Windows7APICodePack" 1.0.0.0 (the one which comes from Microsoft)

Comment: It looks like in 1.0.0.0 you don't have this issue with icons - it is new to 1.1.0.0

Comment: That's right but this version does not offer CommonOpenFileDialog so I'm screwed. Update your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Looks like setting "dialog.InstructionText" in .Opened handler second time (to the same value) fixes it for 1.1 as well (forces dialog to recalculate it's size)

Comment: There's a fix for the icon issue : http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=108

Comment: I've made an updated NuGet package with the bug fixed, the link is on my edit.